# How to change the label color of NavigationDestination in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have the following NavigationBar with a "dark mode".
By default, the color of the labels are dark.
How can I change the color to be white?

```
NavigationBar(
      labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.onlyShowSelected,
      selectedIndex: currentIndex,
      onDestinationSelected: onTap,
      destinations: const <Widget>[
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined, color: ColorPalette.gray),
          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded, color: ColorPalette.white),
          label: "Home",
        ),
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.playlist_add_outlined, color: ColorPalette.gray),
          selectedIcon:
              Icon(Icons.playlist_add_rounded, color: ColorPalette.white),
          label: 'Playlists',
        ),
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline_rounded, color: ColorPalette.gray),
          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.person_rounded, color: ColorPalette.white),
          label: 'Profile',
        ),
      ],
      backgroundColor: ColorPalette.darkGreen,
      indicatorColor: ColorPalette.green,
    );
```

I've searched multiple documentations and tutorials but didn't find an answer.
I tried to change the TextTheme in the MaterialApp but it didn't changed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the label color in the [ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) by setting the [labelTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBarThemeData/labelTextStyle.html) in [navigationBarTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/navigationBarTheme.html).

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    navigationBarTheme: NavigationBarThemeData(
      labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
        TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    navigationBarTheme: NavigationBarThemeData(
      labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
        TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```